# Max Expected Floating Point Error in Python

Tags: python, floating-point

I have the following method in my python code that compares values between two objects to determine if they are equal:

```
def equals(self, vec, tol):
        return all(i < tol for i in [abs(a - b) for a, b in zip(self, vec)])
```

I want to give a default value to my tolerance variable, `tol`, such that it is the smallest possible value that is always greater than error that could occur from floating-point inaccuracies. What is this value?

Comment: Depending on the arithmetic operations, the error can become arbitrarily large.

Comment: True, so should the tolerance depend on the size of the values I'm comparing?

Comment: Right. One usual way is to multiply tolerance with `max(abs(a), abs(b))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually use something like this with numpy:

```
tol = max(np.finfo(float).eps, np.finfo(float).eps * abs(a - b))
```

Answer (score 1):

The largest possible error is infinity, and NaN (Not a Number) is also possible. There is **no general formula** that is correct for `tol`. Determining what error could occur **always** requires knowledge of the values used and the operations performed.

Additionally, there are limited situations where “comparing for equality using a tolerance” is a proper technique. (Testing software is one of them.) Comparing for equality using a tolerance reduces the risk of deciding two numbers are unequal even though they would be equal if computed with exact mathematics, but it does so at the expense of falsely accepting as equal two numbers that would be unequal if computed with exact mathematics. Even deciding **whether** such a trade-off is acceptable is application-dependent, let alone deciding what the tolerance should be.

Comment: I have come to understand what you said in your first paragraph by previous comments. However, I don't understand your described trade off. If two numbers differ by less than the default tolerance (which is the smallest possible floating point error) can a computer even reliably distinguish those two numbers? If so, couldn't a 0 tolerance be passed to get the regular expected behavior?

Comment: If two numbers *x* and *y* are close together and both round to the same floating-point number, then no direct computation of those numbers would be able to distinguish them. If one were attempting to distinguish them, one might compute *x*−*y* (by which I mean perform some computation whose result is mathematically *x*−*y*, not to compute an `x` and a `y` and then subtract them) and compare it to zero. Regarding your second question, a zero tolerance would cause the `equals` in the question to always return false, as it uses `< tol`. With `<= tol`, a zero `tol` would make it effectively `==`.